# Call web service over HTTP on HTTPS page

Tags: ajax, https, network-protocols, web-services

I am having problems calling a web service using AJAX via HTTP when it's on an HTTPS page.

Is this a cross-domain/protocol problem?  Do I need to do the AJAX call in the same protocol as the page?

Just wondering if it's the same problem as trying to do an HTTPS AJAX call when on an HTTP page, I suspect it is.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks
Duncan

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the protocol is part of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: Thanks that's what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. You run a serious risk of someone intercepting and modifying just the HTTP traffic to break your security.